# How do I override the delete button on VF page to return to parent?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, button-overrides

I have a VF page displaying a custom object with it's child objects in repeating apex:detail sections. Each section displays the child with the standard edit, delete,clone buttons that are there like when you open the child object by itself.
[image]

Everything works fine, except when clicking delete (to delete one of the child objects), which does delete the child but doesn't return to the parent VF page.

I tried creating a VF + controller to override the std delete button on the child, but the parameter it passes is the parent's one, and I get this error:

Id value a02O000000DdrPj is not valid for the CallCycleActivity__c standard controller

The id is for the parent, and CallCycleActivity__c is the child which is being deleted.

I need to delete the child and to return to the parent. How do I get it do this?

```
<apex:page standardController="CallCycleActivity__c" extensions="CCADeleteOverrideExt" action="{!customDelete}">
```

```
public with sharing class CCADeleteOverrideExt {

private CallCycleActivity__c cca;    
public PageReference pageRef;
public Map<string,string> URLParameters = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();

public CCADeleteOverrideExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

    this.cca = (CallCycleActivity__c)stdController.getRecord();

    //The return URL is passed via the custom button - get this to know where to return after a Save or Cancel
    if(URLParameters.containsKey('retURL')){
        pageRef = new PageReference(URLParameters.get('retURL'));
    }

}

public PageReference customDelete(){
    delete cca;

    // Return whatever PageReference you want here
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;       
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the redirect to URL of the parent via parent's record id, i.e.

```
public PageReference customDelete(){
  PageReference ret = new PageReference('/' + cca.parent__c); //replace parent__c with appropriate relationship field
  delete cca;
  ret.setRedirect(true);
  return ret;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customDelete pagereference should redirect to the VF page passing the parent URL again - try setting it explicitly using the parent ID instead of using the existing pageRef. Instantiate a new Ref.